# How to prove that sub-level set of spectral radius function is not convex

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\rho(A)=\{|\lambda|_\max : \lambda \text{ is an eigen-value of } A\}$. I am trying to prove that the set 
\begin{align*}
B_\alpha=\{A: \rho(A) < \alpha \}
\end{align*}
need not be a convex set in general (for any $\alpha>0$). Can anyone provide a useful hint about how to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the $2 \times 2$ matrices $\pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 1 & 0\cr}$ and 
$\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ have spectral radius $0$, but their average
has positive spectral radius.