# Convex constraint on spectral radius

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization

Let $A$ be a square matrix. I need to perform the Euclidean projection onto the set of matrices with a constrained spectral radius:

$$\min_A\,\lVert A_0-A\rVert_F$$

$$\mathrm{such\;that}\hspace{1em}f(A) \leqslant1, \hspace{1em} A > 0$$
where $ f(A) = \rho(B)$ and $B_{ij} = e^{-A_{ij}}$ is the element-wise exponent.

I believe the set $f(A)\leqslant1\,$ is convex by [Kingman 1961](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/12/1/283/1534893)

What is the recommended method to solve this problem?

Comment: To be sure ; is $\| ... \|_2$ the matrix norm associated with vector norm $\|...\|_2$, i.e. $\sup_X \|AX\|_2 / \|X\|_2$ ?

Comment: Don't you mean the spectral radius is constrained?

Comment: This seems relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4203937/443030

Comment: @JeanMarie I mean the Frobenius norm, updated in original post.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes, updated!

Comment: The constraint is not convex over all $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2207782/443030, so you also need to introduce a normality constraint $AA^* = A^*A$. Also see this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39002/optimizing-over-matrices-with-spectral-radius-1

Comment: Thanks everyone. @V.S.e.H. you're right, this constraint is not convex. I slightly updated the question to better reflect our actual problem (spectral radius of the element-wise exponential of -A). I believe _that_ might be convex, but I'm working on verifying it.

Comment: Yes, I believe that should be log-convex by Kingman 1961:  
https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/12/1/283/1534893